# How to control tickInterval of datetime in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating a simple spline chart using highcharts, here xAxis is of type 'datetime' and yAxis has random values between (0 - 100), the timeinterval is exactly one minute between each and every object of series data, i have set minTickInterval as 60000, but whenever the page is loaded the chart has correctly 5 ticks but i'm not able to see tick label

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          zoomType: 'x',
          animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
          marginRight: 10,
          events: {

          }
      },

      time: {
          useUTC: false
      },

      title: {
          text: 'usage'
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          tickInterval: 60000
      },

      yAxis: {
          plotLines: [{
              value: 0,
              width: 1,
              color: '#003366'
          }]
      },

      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
          pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
      },

      legend: {
          enabled: false
      },

      exporting: {
          enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions:{
        series:{
            turboThreshold:0
        }
      },
      series: [{
          data: [
           {x: new Date("Mon Apr 27 2020 11:41:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"),y: 42},
            {x: new Date("Mon Apr 27 2020 11:42:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"),y: 4},
            {x: new Date("Mon Apr 27 2020 11:43:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"),y: 4},
            {x: new Date("Mon Apr 27 2020 11:44:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"),y: 4},
            {x: new Date("Mon Apr 27 2020 11:45:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"),y: 4}
          ]
      }]
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/no-data-to-display.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you have in mind by saying that you are not able to see the ticks? I reproduced your code and everything looks fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fa6odnjt/

Comment: I cant see tick labels in this too https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fa6odnjt/

Comment: Don't you see the time xAxis tick labels? Like: 8:12, 8:13, 8:14 etc?

Comment: No SebastianWędzel

Comment: On which browser have you opened this demo?